# Is this sentence correct? : This is what should be done to become teacher I was told

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I just tried to make a sentence from these two sentences.

1. Something should be done to become a teacher.
2. I was told that something.
   And I want to say “This is something that I was told”.

So, I made a sentence like below :
“This is what should be done to become a teacher I was told.“

Does it make sense?

Thank you.

Comment: No.  Try "I was told that this is something that should done be done to become a teacher".

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is something along the lines of: `I have been told that this is what needs to be done to become a teacher.`

If you actually know it, and want to include the 'thing' then: `I have been told that to become a teacher <something> needs to be done.`

The example you gave does not really make sense as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence has two main verbs: "is" and "told." So it is incorrect.

I think that you meant to use indirect speech, as in:

> I was told that this is what should be done to become a teacher.